# How do I override the variable that was given a value to in another class which has been inherited

Tags: java, class, inheritance, overriding, superclass

I am trying to get user input for the number of seats a car has in the super class but make a method that prints the number of seats in the subclass called "Car". However, when I state the variable that stores the user input I get an error stating the variable is not visible and that is because it is in another class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Vehicle {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    private String color;
    private int noOfCylinders;
    private int noOfSeats;

    public Vehicle() {
        color = "Black";
        noOfCylinders = 0;
        noOfSeats = 1;
    }

    public Vehicle(String color, int noOfCylinders, int noOfSeats) {
        this.color = color;
        this.noOfCylinders = noOfCylinders;
        this.noOfSeats = noOfSeats;
    }

    public void getColor() {
        System.out.print("Enter color of vehicle: ");
        color = s.nextLine();
    }

    public String setColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void getNoOfCylinders() {
        System.out.print("Enter number of cylinders: ");
        noOfCylinders = s.nextInt();
    }

    public int setNoOfCylinders() {
        return noOfCylinders;
    }

    public void getNoOfSeats() {
        System.out.print("Enter numer of seats: ");
        int noOfSeats = s.nextInt();
    }

    public String toString() {
        String information;
        information = "is " + color + " and it has " + noOfCylinders + " cylinders.";
        return information;
    }
}

public class CreateVehicle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Car CarObject = new Car();
        Truck TruckObject = new Truck();

        CarObject.getColor();
        CarObject.setColor();
        CarObject.getNoOfCylinders();
        CarObject.setNoOfCylinders();
        CarObject.toString();
        CarObject.getNumOfSeats();

        TruckObject.getColor();
        TruckObject.setColor();
        TruckObject.getNoOfCylinders();
        TruckObject.setNoOfCylinders();
        TruckObject.toString();

        System.out.print(("\nThe car ")+CarObject.toString());
        System.out.print(("\nThe truck ")+TruckObject.toString());      
    }
}


class Car extends Vehicle{

    public void getNumOfSeats(){
        System.out.print("\nThe car has " + noOfSeats + " seats.");
    }
}


    class Truck extends Vehicle {
        public void printTowingCapacity() {
            System.out.print("\nThe car has " + towingCapacity + ".");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use the getter instead of access the variable directly directly

Comment: You have some serious issues in the way your code is structured.  `getNoOfSeats()` should be returning the number of seats, not reading in the value from the user.  Fixing your code is too broad for StackOverflow, you need to get some help from your professor.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on OOP concept you can't access private variabale outside the class not even in child class.

Here you have declare

```
 private int noOfSeats;
```

And you try to access it outside the class in child which is out of private variable scope.

To access it in child class make noOfSeats variable

```
 public int noOfSeats;
```

or

```
 protected int noOfSeats;
```

in Vehicle class.

If you want to put noOfSeats variable as private the create on public function on vehicitle class (parent class) and call it from Car class (child class).

And you are try to access

```
 System.out.print("\nThe car has " + towingCapacity + ".")
```

towingCapacity variable in Truck class and you have't declare it in either Vehicle class or Truck class.

So first declare it then use it.

For more details about java access modifier read this article

https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/access-modifiers-in-java/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the public function of the parent class, getNoOfSeats(), if you want to keep the variables private.

```
class Car extends Vehicle{
   public void getNumOfSeats(){
      System.out.print("\nThe car has " + super.getNoOfSeats() + " seats.");
   }
}
```

Or just change the variable noOfSeats to protected or package-protected,

Comment: This will result in a compiler error, since `Vehicle.getNoOfSeats` has void return type. It is not a proper getter. It is good practice to test your answer code before posting.

Answer (score 0):

noOfSeats is a private member of the class which cannot be accessed by any other class. If you want to make it accessible from inherited class, make it access specifier to protected.